# ¿Como definir una secuencia en oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Si tengo una tabla en la que la llave primaria es de  data_type number(10,0)

¿Es correcto definir mi secuencia así para se almacene como mi llave primaria?

```
create sequence seq_libros
  start with 1
  increment by 1
  maxvalue 99999
  minvalue 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La instruccion para crear la secuncia es correcta, sin embargo solo va a crecer hasta el numero 99999 y tu columna acepta hasta 10 digitos por que lo el numero maximo aceptado por la columna seria 9999999999.

Otra cosa, de alguna manera tienes que consumir la secuencia y asignar a tu llave primaria.

Opcion 1:
Consultar el siguiente valor y asignar al registro antes de crearlo

Opcion 2:
Crear un triger que se ejecute, despues del insert y que vaya a consultar la secuencia.

Saludos

Israel Ramos